# SpringBoot JPA Many-to-Many relationship - Rest Webservice unable to return child objects

Tags: hibernate, rest, jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many

I need help in retrieving data from a Spring Boot application using JPA to handle Many-to-Many relationships. I’m having trouble getting the child entities of a parent entity.

I have a simple many to many relationship established: Owner <-> Book <-> Publisher

When I do a GET on the controller to fetch data about a Book, I only get the Book’s attributes. No information about the associated Owner or Publisher is returned. What am I missing?

Executing `cURL -XGET http://localhost:8080/books` only returns the attributes from the book and not the dependent objects:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Book 1",
      "isbn":"978-0743246261"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Book 2",
      "isbn":"978-0743246262"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Book 3",
      "isbn":"978-0743246263"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Book 4",
      "isbn":"978-0743246264"
   }
]
```

I’ve setup the project in GitHub and it is ready to run and test right away: https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-spring-boot-many-2-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default many-to-many relation fetch with strategy **lazy**, means until you don't call the method to retrieve the many to many relationship objects from your main Object, hibernate will not load them from the database.

Please set the fetch strategy EAGER so hibernate will load many2many relationship during the loading of your main object

```
fetch=FetchType.EAGER
```

example code:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userGroups", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, that doesn't help. Please see my updated code: https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-spring-boot-many-2-many

Comment: when i am ruuning your app, getting 2018-01-01 23:25:51.574  WARN 1557 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class net.tekpartner.learn.many2many.persistence.model.Book]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid Object Id definition for net.tekpartner.learn.many2many.persistence.model.Book: cannot find property with name 'id'
during hit api http://localhost:8080/books/isbn/978-0743246264

Comment: That's odd. I had removed the Jackson dependency as it worked with out it. I've put it back now. Please get the latest.

Comment: i took pull but now it's throwing             Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class net.tekpartner.learn.many2many.persistence.model.Book

Comment: I pulled the code to a new machine and tried again. It worked for me. I wonder why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: i think  you need to use    JsonManagedReference on private Set<Owner> owners as well as private Set<Publisher> publishers  instead of use of JsonBackReference in book class also in publisher and owner class replace  JsonManagedReference with  JsonBackReference

Comment: Thanks @bhushan-uniyal. That did the trick. I had to swap the references JsonManagedReference & JsonBackReference, and it worked. Pushed the code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution as pointed above by @bhushan-uniyal was to swap the references JsonManagedReference & JsonBackReference, and it worked. Pushed the code and it worked.